# Adding Coldfusion10 dictionary to CFEclipse Plugin

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfeclipse

I downloaded CfEclipse plugin (http://www.cfeclipse.org/update) for Eclipse 4.2.2. I can't see the support for Coldfusion 10. How to add Coldfusion 10 tags/functions?

Comment: Try `http://cfeclipse.org/update-preview` update site - it has a newer version and may well include a CF10 dictionary (not sure).

If it doesn't, either [raising an issue](https://github.com/cfeclipse/cfeclipse/issues) or asking on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/group/cfeclipse-users) would be the best route.

(Adding the dictionary is pretty much just creating a cf10.xml file, so if it doesn't exist it's not too hard to do yourself.)

Comment: @PeterBoughton Thanks. I updated the plugin to 1.4.5.201112121854. But the Cf10 dictionary is missing. Where can I get the authentic cf10.xml file?

Comment: Coldfusion Builder shares the same dictionary format - download the latest version and extract it from there

Answer (score 3):

Use the CFML 10 and CFML 11 dictionary from a CFBuilder3 install, which uses the same dictionary format. Just take the dictionary from CFBuilder3  and drop it into the CFBuilder2 dictionary folder and add the following to the "dictionaryconfig.xml" file:

```
<version key="ColdFusion11" label="ColdFusion 11">
       <grammar location="cf11.xml" />
</version>

<version key="ColdFusion10" label="ColdFusion 10">
       <grammar location="cf10.xml" />
</version>
```

The dictionary files are located in the "CFBuilder" plugins directory and have the word "dictionary" in the folder name—for example:

E:\cfbuilder\plugins\com.adobe.ide.coldfusion.dictionary_2.0.1.282422\dictionary